# Finite dimension quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, quotient-spaces, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $R=C[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $M$ be a maximal ideal of $R$ such that $R/M$ is a finite dimensional $C-$algebra. Can we deduce that $R/M^n$ for n>1 is also finite dimensional $C$-algebra?

We know that $M^n\subset M$ so $R/M \subset R/M^n$. However we cannot conclude that $R/M^n$ is also finite dimensional.

Also we know that since $M$ is maximal, $M=(x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n)$, so $R/M$ is isomorphic to $C$. I don't know if we can conclude that $R/M^n$ is also finite dimensional.

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong: $M^n\subset M$ does **not** imply that we have an injective map $R/M\to R/M^n$.

In fact, it induces a morphism of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras $R/M^n\to R/M$, which is **surjective**. Hence $\dim(R/M^n)\geq \dim(R/M)$.

Comment: Is there any counter example that $R/M^n$ is infinite dimensional?

Comment: How about if $M$ is a maximal ideal?

Comment: What is $C$? Arbitrary field?

Comment: $C$ is the field of complex numbers

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[X_1, \cdots, X_n]$ and $m=(x_1-a_1, \cdots x_n-a_n)$ be a maximal ideal of $R$.  $R/m = \mathbb{C}$.

$m^k$ is generated by $\{(x_1-a_1)^{e_1}\cdots(x_n-a_n)^{e_n} \colon \sum_j e_j = k\}$ and $R/m^k$ is generated by $\{(x_1-a_1)^{i_1}\cdots (x_n-a_n)^{i_n}\colon \sum_j i_j < k\}$. Then $R/m^k$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: I initially posted general version of this theorem ("m is not necesarily maximal" version), but it was incorrect proof, so I deleted it. Somebody knows if the general version holds?